# Oracle: How to sort the query to get months in proper sequence

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am working on an report for which am calling a function from front end. I am getting start month information as numbers starting from 1 to 12 and so am using

```
substr(to_date(START_MONTH,'MM'),4,3)
```

to get month in the form of Jan, Feb etc, now in my function am grouping by start month and then ordering by start month and so in the output am getting values like

Apr, Aug, Dec as it is ordering by First alphabet of the month, how can I get correct order starting from Jan to Dec?

Any suggestions?

Also how to sort number so that 2 comes after 1 and not 10 after 1?

Comment: please consider using `to_char(to_date(start_date, 'MM'), 'Mon')` instead of substr() (which does an implicit to_char() anyway).

Comment: @Martin - Why do you recommend to use `to_char` instead of `substr`?

Comment: The substr() converts the date to a string with your default NLS date format. Different date format == different results. Try it: type `alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD'` and then see what the substr() returns. The to_char() specifies an explicit format and does not rely on the default date format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> order by to_date( start_month, 'mm' )

?

Comment: thanks randy...i know understand the importance of taking short breaks :)

Comment: a second pair of eyes always helps.  even if you imagine them :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
select TO_CHAR(T1.SCHDATE, 'Mon-YY') FROM FINSCHEDULEDETAILS T1  
 GROUP BY TO_CHAR(T1.SCHDATE, 'Mon-YY'),TO_CHAR(T1.SCHDATE, 'YYMM')
    ORDER BY TO_CHAR(T1.SCHDATE, 'YYMM'));
```